# Call function every time any component updates (including route change)

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to call a function every time *anything* in React updates?

A little more context:
I want to use the full capabilities of [EQCSS](http://elementqueries.com/) in React. I've tried 2 NPM packages, but they didn't seem to do what I expected exactly.

What I would like to do, is every time *any* component updates, I want to call `EQCSS.apply()`.

I've tried calling in `componentDidUpdate` but this doesn't seem to work when changing pages (using react-router) for example.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from "react-router";

import { MainLayout } from "./layouts";
import {
    HomePage,
    RankingsPage
} from "./routes";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route component={MainLayout}>
                    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/rankings" component={RankingsPage} />
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log("COMPONENT UPDATED");
        // This does not get called when changing pages.
    }
}

// Render the main component into the dom
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: none of the component lifecycle methods are called ?? i saw a readMe where what all lifecycle methods are called when route changes are provided  : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md

Comment: componentDidUpdate wasn't called when changing pages. But I'm looking for any way possible. Doesn't have to be that per sé :)

Comment: @VishnuShekhawat thank you for that link. Seems I should call `componentDidUpdate()` in a component being called from the Router. Changed it to be called in `MainLayout` and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are three different ways you could achieve this:

---

1. **React Context**

   - Demo: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/GjvzdJ
   - React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

---

2. **MutationObserver**

Wrap your main parent component in the  `MutationObserver`. More info here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/

`MutationObserver` will track *any* changes to the *actual* DOM tree.

---

3. **Callback functions passed vie props**

I've demonstrated another approach here: https://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/wzqQkx. Please check the console which logs messages every time something has happened on the page, including Route changes, or **re-renders of deeply nested children components**. This relies however on a callback passed down through the child hierarchy via props.

**Ad 1. Context demo code:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.bool
  };

  getChildContext() {
    return {data: true};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <Child />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Child extends React.Component {       
  static contextTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    console.log('in Child', this.context.data)
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Child</h3>
        <Grandchild />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Grandchild extends React.Component {       
  static contextTypes = {
    data: React.PropTypes.bool
  };

  render() {
    console.log('in Grandchild', this.context.data)
    return (
      <div>
        <h6>Grandchild</h6>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

**Ad 3. Callback demo code:**

```
var MainLayout = React.createClass({
  doSomething: function() {
    console.log('something happened');
  },

  render: function() {
    this.doSomething();
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
     (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
       doSomething: this.doSomething
     })
    );

    return (
      <div className="app">
        <header className="primary-header"></header>
        <aside className="primary-aside">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/users">Users</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/widgets">Widgets</Link></li>
          </ul>
        </aside>
        <main>
          {childrenWithProps}
        </main>
      </div>
      )
  }
})

var Home = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      counter: 1
    };
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.props.doSomething()
  },

  changeCounter: function() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.changeCounter}>Click me</button>
        <br />
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
})

var SearchLayout = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
      (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
       doSomething: this.props.doSomething
     })
    );

    return (
      <div className="search">
        <header className="search-header"></header>
        <div className="results">
          {childrenWithProps}
        </div>
        <div className="search-footer pagination"></div>
      </div>
      )
  }
})

var UserList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      counter: 1
    };
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.props.doSomething()
  },

  changeCounter: function() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        User List
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.changeCounter}>Click me</button>
        <br />
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var WidgetList = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      counter: 1
    };
  },

  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    this.props.doSomething()
  },

  changeCounter: function() {
    this.setState({
      counter: this.state.counter + 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        Widgets
        <br />
        <button onClick={this.changeCounter}>Click me</button>
        <br />
        {this.state.counter}
      </div>
    );
  }
})



ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route component={SearchLayout}>
        <Route path="users" component={UserList} />
        <Route path="widgets" component={WidgetList} />
      </Route> 
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: Using MutationObserver seems a bit overkill, since it will react to all DOM events? But also, passing the handler to all components is quite some work too. Is there no way of making all components inherit the same code? I know ES6 base classes are not recommended, but might this not be a good use-case for that?

Comment: You could also use React context. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Still not sure what approach to take, but I'll mark this as answer. Seems to me you gave me enough info to work with. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would probably start by investigating React context to see if it can give me the required business logic. Bear in mind that it is an experimental feature. However many React libraries rely on it at the moment, e.g. React Router, Redux.

Answer (score 1):

Thank to @VishnuShekhawat's [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md), it was shown I waited for the `componentDidUpdate()` function at the wrong place.
Changed it to the `MainLayout` component, and there it was called on page/route change.

Comment: Is `componentDidUpdate()` on parent called when children elements are re-rendered?

Comment: Apparently not ... That seems to be the next challenge - as I don't want to pass the handler to all my child components. Seems a lot of work if you have lots of components in the tree. Perhaps a higher order component is a solution?